# Elantech Touchpad on Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, hp, hp-touchpad

I'm running ubuntu gnome 16.04.1 on my hp pavilion ab048tx (ci5 5th) having an Elantech touchpad. I've tried various dkms fixes available on the internet (including psmouse-elantech-x551c and psmouse-elantech-v7), but nothing seems to get multi-touch into action. Basic functions work (move, click, tap and right-click). Any idea what to do?

My (partial) output for cat **/proc/bus/input/devices** is as follows:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="PS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event6 
B: PROP=1
B: EV=7
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3
```

For demsg | grep elantech, it is:

```
[    2.123958] psmouse serio1: elantech: unknown hardware version, aborting...
[    2.429095] input: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[ 2506.145724] psmouse serio1: elantech: unknown hardware version, aborting...
[ 2506.449970] input: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input20
```

For synclient -l

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

Relevant output from Xorg.0.log:

```
[    28.346] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/event6)
[    28.346] (**) PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    28.347] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event6 13:70 fd 38 paused 0
[    28.347] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'PS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
[    28.347] (**) PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: always reports core events
[    28.347] (**) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Device: "/dev/input/event6"
[    28.347] (--) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x1
[    28.347] (--) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Found 3 mouse buttons
[    28.347] (--) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Found relative axes
[    28.347] (--) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Found x and y relative axes
[    28.347] (II) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Configuring as mouse
[    28.347] (**) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    28.347] (**) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    28.347] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5/event6"
[    28.347] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "PS/2 Elantech Touchpad" (type: MOUSE, id 13)
[    28.347] (II) evdev: PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: initialized for relative axes.
[    28.347] (**) PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    28.347] (**) PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    28.347] (**) PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    28.347] (**) PS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    28.347] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    28.347] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    28.347] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

Please ask for more if needed!

Comment: I have the same issue as yours with the same elantech touchpad. What update did you get? Does the touchpad still works after suspend? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it does. The update that probably changed everything was the latest kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an update a couple of hours back that solved this issue. Everything is working now!! Tap to click, natural scrolling and so on. Loving ubuntu <3!

Probably the latest kernel that solves everything!
The transition was kernel **4.4.0-38 from 4.4.0-36**.